# 'Worksheet' object has no attribute '_merged_cells'

Tags: merge, openpyxl

I have been reading all material related to fix the excel border problem when merging cells with openpyxl. My problem is that I am trying to implement the monkeypatch mentioned solution from bucketlist and mentioned in other posts here, but I keep getting an error when running it.

AttributeError: 'Worksheet' object has no attribute '_merged_cells'

Anyone that can point me in the right direction?

```py
from itertools import product
import types
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import worksheet
from openpyxl.utils import range_boundaries
from openpyxl import Workbook

def patch_worksheet():
    """This monkeypatches Worksheet.merge_cells to remove cell deletion bug
    https://bitbucket.org/openpyxl/openpyxl/issues/365/styling-merged-cells-isnt-working
    Thank you to Sergey Pikhovkin for the fix
    """

    def merge_cells(self, range_string=None, start_row=None, start_column=None, end_row=None, end_column=None):
        """ Set merge on a cell range.  Range is a cell range (e.g. A1:E1)
        This is monkeypatched to remove cell deletion bug
        https://bitbucket.org/openpyxl/openpyxl/issues/365/styling-merged-cells-isnt-working
        """
        if not range_string and not all((start_row, start_column, end_row, end_column)):
            msg = "You have to provide a value either for 'coordinate' or for\
            'start_row', 'start_column', 'end_row' *and* 'end_column'"
            raise ValueError(msg)
        elif not range_string:
            range_string = '%s%s:%s%s' % (get_column_letter(start_column),
                                          start_row,
                                          get_column_letter(end_column),
                                          end_row)
        elif ":" not in range_string:
            if COORD_RE.match(range_string):
                return  # Single cell, do nothing
            raise ValueError("Range must be a cell range (e.g. A1:E1)")
        else:
            range_string = range_string.replace('$', '')

        if range_string not in self._merged_cells:
            self._merged_cells.append(range_string)


        # The following is removed by this monkeypatch:

        # min_col, min_row, max_col, max_row = range_boundaries(range_string)
        # rows = range(min_row, max_row+1)
        # cols = range(min_col, max_col+1)
        # cells = product(rows, cols)

        # all but the top-left cell are removed
        #for c in islice(cells, 1, None):
            #if c in self._cells:
                #del self._cells[c]

    # Apply monkey patch
    m = types.MethodType(merge_cells, None, worksheet.Worksheet)
    worksheet.Worksheet.merge_cells = m

wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.create_sheet('Mysheet')
patch_worksheet()

ws.merge_cells('A21:C21')

test_cell = ws['A21']
test_cell.value = 'My comment'
test_cell.border = Border(top=medium, left=medium, right=medium, bottom=medium)
test_cell.font  = Font(b=True, color='000000')
test_cell.alignment = Alignment(horizontal='center', vertical='center')

wb.save('test.xlsx')
```

Comment: Just use openpyxl >= 2.6 which handles merged cells safely.